# Removing Switch Statements in Enums

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

For an arena game, I have an enum of possible gametypes. Each of these gametypes has a list of variants associated with it along with 2 classes per enum that listen for events and handle configuration values. Currently, I construct these listeners and config loaders from the enum. In doing so, I have to use a switch statement though. The following method gets the listener from an enum value.

```
public GameListener getListener(CustomGame cg) {
    switch(this) {
    case Slayer:
        return new SlayerListener(cg);
    case Capture_The_Flag:
        return new CaptureTheFlagListener(cg);
    case Oddball:
        return new OddballListener(cg);
    case HeadHunter:
        return new HeadHunterListener(cg);
    case King_Of_The_Hill:
        return new KOTHListener(cg);
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Similar code exists for configs. I know that using abstract methods I can remove the switch statements, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way. I tried to make my enum take 2 type parameters, but I couldn't get that to work, and I wouldn't be able to construct with them. One option is to pass in the `Class<T>` and construct the object through reflection.

There is another method in this class that has very different layouts for each enum, and I think the best option for that would be abstract methods, but I feel like there is a simpler solution here.

Comment: Your solution is already the simplest one (and the best one in terms of performance).  You can make it look cleaner by putting the `return` statements on the same lines as the `case` statements.

Comment: If performance does not count here (and I suppose it doesn't), and you want to optimize the case away to have no requirement to maintain it with new enums coming in, I suggest you add the class to create the listener to the enum as a parameter and call newInstance() on it. Have a setCustomGame() method on the Listener interface and call that to init the listener.

Comment: @Robert The only problem is that I have to manually update each switch statement every time I add an enum value, which is pretty often.

Comment: @thst This is what I want to happen, except that I can easily just pass the custom game as a parameter to the constructor instead of adding that method. (CustomGame is final and modifying it would break a LOT.)

Comment: The design looks sound to me, although I would rather create a `ListenerFactory.createListenerFor(GameType type)` instead of directly using the enum. Enum's are pretty restrictive as you cannot add any state. Personally I don't *feel* comfortable when a `GameType` creates a listener, and I'm pretty much tuned to listen to those kind of signs by now (took only 25 years of developing :P) Oh, yeah, throw an `IllegalStateException` instead of returning `null` if possible.

Comment: @owlstead So you would recommend that createListener method over the GameType defined method? I suppose I could do this, but that method would either need a switch statement, or some sort of stored data in the GameType enum (a Class<? extends GameListener> maybe). Would you recommend storing that Class and using it in the factory method?

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit too precise here. You could go for andrews solution and refactor if required (make a comment somewhere). The only way I see to make this less verbose is to create a trick using reflection, but I would think twice before going that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit more verbose, but you can provide a factory method directly on an enum type:

```
public enum GameType {
  SLAYER {
    @Override
    public GameListener getListener(CustomGame cg)
      return new SlayerListener(cg);
    }
  },
  // ... similarly for other GameListener types

  public abstract GameListener getListener(CustomGame cg);
}
```

The good part about this solution is that it is now impossible to create a new `GameType` without defining an implementation of the `getListener()` method.

Comment: I would use this method if it didn't take up a huge blob of code per GameType. There are currently 2 methods that would need this implementation, and there may be more if I make them more modular. This is definitely an alternative I would consider if it doesn't work out.

Comment: Unfortunately it's often the case with Java that the closest-to-semantically-ideal implementation is also a more verbose one. In this case, where you're defining some kind of custom behavior by enum types, it's either this or something like the switch solution which you've already laid out.

Comment: Very well, I have decided to go with this solution. It may take up more space, but finding all info about a certain GameType is now found in their instantiation.

Comment: @CrypticStorm If you've decided this is the best answer, then don't forget to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

This is a factory method, I think it's perfectly valid to use a switch in this scenario. The alternative would be to create an inheritance hierarchy of Listeners, and declare a reference to the (possibly abstract) superclass of the listeners, while at runtime you'll instantiate the correct listener for the reference. Maybe too much of a hassle, but more object-oriented. It's a tradeoff between nice OO design requiring a lot of classes vs. code full of switch statements, take your pick.

Comment: I think I see where you're going with this, however it would require updating if I add an enum value, which I'm trying to avoid. The Listeners are only constructed through this class, and I would like for that to stay.

Answer (score 0):

If performance doesn't matter, you can have a generic GameListener Getter like this:

```
public Listener getListener( CustomGame cg ) {
    // implement some smart way to find your listener implementation here...
    Class<? extends Listener> clzz = Class.forName( this.getClass().getPackage() + "." + name() );
    Listener ret = clzz.newInstance();
    ret.setCustomGame(cg);
    return ret;
}
```

This will require no maintenance and no special parameters in your enum. But of course, it will link the enum name directly to the created class name, which may not be a desired constraint.